# How to dynamically import static information, including an image, into an ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, feed, data-import

I was wondering whether it was possible to import static information, in my case an image, title and a short description - per item, in a `UIViewControlller` dynamically?

I'm (trying to) create an app that, for the current `UIViewController` I'm working on, shows the cooperating partners from the company in a list view. Each of them is shown as an item, containing an image (logo), the company name below and below that a paragraph of information about the company.

I was thinking of something like importing an `XML` feed (no experience with),
such as

```
<object>
    <img src="/images/logo1.png">
    <title="Lorem ipsum>
    <description="lalalalalalalala"
</object>

<object>
    <img src="/images/logo2.png">
    <title="Lorem second one>
    <description="lalalalalalalala"
</object>
```

Something like this mockup
[image]

By simply importing such thing, I don't have to make up the whole page, calculate how long the `UIScrollView` would have to be and don't have to adjust it every time a partner gets added or removed. And it might be quite more clear than a whole view controller.

Comment: That's a tall order.  Everything you said is possible, but in many pieces.  I would recommend reading into UITableView and NSXMLParser.  Those are the two main building blocks you will need for your view.

Comment: I was expecting such comment already. I got to add, I'm not looking for a simple table view. I've added a mockup image of something I would like to reproduce. Does that makes any difference?

Comment: "Simple" Tableviews can be very robust and they are lazy loading which seems like it would be ideal for your situation.  All of your data can be split into identically formed objects with different data which is exactly what UITableView was created for.  I stand by my original message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to divide the task into **smaller steps**.

1. Read the data from an `XML` file using `NSXMParser`.
2. Show the data in a `UICollectionView`.

The `XML` part is quite easy. There are many tutorials on the Internet that cover this. For example this one:

- [Parsing XML data with NSXMLParser](http://wiki.cs.unh.edu/wiki/index.php/Parsing_XML_data_with_NSXMLParser)

Second step can be more complicated depending on what kind of a layout you want to achieve. If it is a standard flow layout, the implementation will be fairly simple. Again, there is dozens of tutorials on setting up a `UICollectionView`. Example:

- [Beginning UICollectionView](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12)

Alternatively, you can use `UITableView` to show your data. In this case, the implementation would be simpler than for `UICollectionView`.

More reading:

- [Collection View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCellsandViews/CreatingCellsandViews.html)
- [Event-Driven XML Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/xmlparsing/articles/usingparser.html)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where your XML feed/document is coming from. If you're just manually creating the document, and shipping it along with each version of your app, then all you need to worry about is getting the info from it; take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/xml-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-choose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project), it describes some info-getting libraries. Take a look at [`UIImage`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for info on loading an image from a file. If you instead mean that you want to get information from some kind of remote, it seems like you have to accomplish three things:

1. save a document including this various static info, so that it persists between app launches,
2. load from that document to display the saved information, and
3. keep this document up-to-date with some remote server (?) whence the most current version originates, in perhaps XML format.

First of all, let us assume that inside your application proper, you're going to have the data you want stored as some kind of NSObject. Check out [this tutorial](http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/Saving_Data/NSKeyedArchiver.html) on how to save documents with your iPhone app. It explains fairly clearly how to take something like an array or dictionary (OBJC object) and store it. In the end, because your app is sandboxed you may not need to worry about the format in which it is stored. Whenever your application launches, and decides that it has current info, all it needs to do is load from that archived object and you're good to go. If you have some confusion about displaying the information in the UIView itself, refer to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html).

You'll probably want to have a separate class altogether that handles keeping the data updated. This depends on your server's implementation. For example, your class could query your server for its info, determine with a hash whether it needs to get new data, and if so, pull down new data; use NSXMLParser as linked to above in order to parse the data, then save with the above method.

**EDIT**: regarding your worry about having to redesign the UIViewController every time you load, look into auto layout. You basically can create a nib file for your controller, tell it how everything will be in relation to everything else, then just assign values (i.e., images and strings) to all the fields and pow, you've got a consistent design.